# Touch pad occasionally freezes on Asus Laptop

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, asus

The touch pad occasionally freezes on my laptop. If I plug in a USB mouse I can move the cursor but the touch pad remains frozen until after I restart. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Check **`dmesg | grep psmouse`**. Is 'psmouse' driver actually running? This can be delayed (for reasons unknown) for up to 8-10 minutes. *Something to do with power-saving and Windows.* **Are you also running Windows on the PC, or have you recently?**